# Template export troubles

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

I can't understand the right way for exporting some function into python with boost.python.

I have exported this class [CL_Rectf](http://clanlib.org/docs/clanlib-2.2/reference_doxygen/classCL__Rectf.html). It inherits `CL_Rectx<float>`.

Now I want to export function `bounding_rect`:

```
# In CL_Rectf class exporting
.def("BoundingRect", &CL_Rectf::bounding_rect, PYPOLICY_REFERENCE_EXISTING)
```

It compiles, but when I use this code in python:

```
mBox = CL_Rectf()
mBox.BoundingRect(CL_Rectf(x, y, x2, y2))
```

I have such error:

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    CL_Rectf.BoundingRect(CL_Rectf, CL_Rectf)
did not match C++ signature:
    BoundingRect(CL_Rectf {lvalue}, CL_Rectx<float>)
```

Something wrong with exporting due to `CL_Rectx` in c++ signature. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing Boost.Python in particular, it seems to me that you exported `CL_Rectf`, but not `CL_Rectx<float>`. So when asked to convert a python object into a `CL_Rectx<float>`, Boost.Python doesn't know how, and raises the exception you see.

My advice would be be to forget about `CL_Floatf` and export the `CL_Rectx<float>` class instead. `CL_Rectf` as a C++ class is a bad idea on so many levels; you should try to avoid its use even in C++.